# How to get all records with specific enum in a simple_enum rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, enums

spotlight.rb

```
as_enum :media_type, :image => 0,:video => 1
```

When I do

```
Spotlight.last.media_type
```

return nil. But when I do

```
 Spotlight.last.image?
```

it returns true

2nd issue is that it not returns list of all records when I do

```
Spotlight.images
Spotlight.videos
```

Comment: @ahmad You need to set `media_type` for your records. 
`
Spotlight.last.update_attribute(media_type: 1)
` 
Or set default value for you all records.

Comment: have you tried `Spotlight.image` ?